# Ajax call to delete and refresh list not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am implementing an Ajax call to the server to delete a post from a `li`. The delete is working fine, but I need to manually get out from the list page and when I get back the list is updated. What I am trying to achieve, is that when the button that deletes the item, also refreshes the list. I added the following code but is not refreshing :(.

```
function deleteThisPost() {

    //alert($('#myPostIDStorage').val())
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'myPostIDValue=' + $('#myPostIDStorage').val(),
        url: 'http://wander-app.org/deletePosts.php',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Post Deleted!');
        },

        error: function () {
            alert('Error Deleting Post');
        }

    });


    return false;
    $('#myPost').listview("refresh");
};
```

Comment: Write `$( '#myPost' ).listview( "refresh" );` before `return false`
OR `$( '#myPost' ).listview( "refresh" );` write this inside `success`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax call works fine as you can see [there](http://jsfiddle.net/2oof8x81/). You should take a notice that if you return anything from a function it is no longer executed. The code that you provided below `$( '#myPost' ).listview( "refresh" );` will be never examined.

What you probably want to do is

```
function deleteThisPost() {

    //alert($('#myPostIDStorage').val())
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'myPostIDValue=' + $('#myPostIDStorage').val(),
        url: 'http://wander-app.org/deletePosts.php',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function (data) {


            alert('Post Deleted!');
        },

        error: function () {

            alert('Error Deleting Post');

        }

    });

    $('#myPost').listview("refresh");

    return false;
};
```

According to your question if you want a dialog box with cancel and confirm button you can do

```
if(confirm('Do you want to delete?') == true) {
   alert('Deleted');
}
```

Comment: hi @Mateusz Nowak, I realized that the `alert('Post Deleted!')` alert has a confirmation button that says: "Deleted" and then an OK. where the user needs to click. I think the refresh code is not running because of that. How can you add the refresh after the user clicks on the ok from the alert window?

Comment: You should add `confirm` window. See updated answer.